How to ensure file integrity when using pre-signed URLs for S3 uploads in Node.js?
I'm working on an application that allows users to upload files directly to AWS S3 using pre-signed URLs. I'm using the AWS SDK for JavaScript and the getSignedUrl() function to generate the pre-signed URLs.
My current implementation is as follows:
userRouter.js
userRoutes.post("/get-presigned-upload-url", validateJwtToken,
    validateRequest(userValidators.uploadFileSchema),
    awsS3Controller.getPresignedDownloadUrl);

awsS3Controller.js
const awsS3Service = new AWSS3Service();

export const getPresignedUploadUrl = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { folderPath, fileMetadata } = req.body;
        const { contentType, originalFileName, size, ChecksumSHA256 } = fileMetadata;
        const uniqueFileName = awsS3Service.generateUniqueFileName(originalFileName);
        const key = `users/${req.user.id}/${!folderPath ? "" : folderPath}${uniqueFileName}`;
        const presignedUrl = await awsS3Service.generatePresignedUploadUrl(
            key,
            contentType,
            { 
                metadata: { originalFileName, size, ChecksumSHA256 },
                checksumSHA256: ChecksumSHA256
            }
        );
        res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json({ message: "File uploaded successfully", presignedUrl: presignedUrl });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({ message: error.message });
    }   
}

awsS3Service.js
class AWSS3Service {
    async generatePresignedUploadUrl(key, contentType, options = {}) {
        try {
            const command = new PutObjectCommand({
                Bucket: this.bucketName,
                Key: key,
                ContentType: contentType,
                Metadata: options.metadata,
                ACL: options.acl || 'private',
                ChecksumAlgorithm: options.checksumAlgorithm || "SHA256",
                ChecksumSHA256: options.checksumSHA256,                
            });
            return await getSignedUrl(this.s3Client, command, { 
                expiresIn: options.expiresIn || this.defaultExpiry,
                signableHeaders: new Set(['host', 'x-amz-sdk-checksum-algorithm', 'x-amz-checksum-sha256', 'content-type'])
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Presigned URL Generation Error:', error);
            throw new Error(`Failed to generate presigned URL: ${error.message}`);
        }
    }
}

The issue I'm facing is that I want to ensure the file being uploaded to the pre-signed URL is the same as the one used to generate the pre-signed URL. In other words, I want to verify the file integrity between the pre-signed URL generation and the actual file upload.
I've tried using the ChecksumSHA256 option in the PutObjectCommand and the signableHeaders option in the getSignedUrl() function, but I'm still not sure if this is the correct approach. For example, I've also read that I have to turn on checksums in S3.

What is the correct/complete way to achieve this verification?

You say that you tried it. What happened?

@jarmod I was still able to upload a different file than the one I used to generate the getPresignedUploadURL. It didn't seem to restrict the upload to just the specified file.

I'm sending a SHA-256 checksum generated using certutil -hashfile "C:\<path>.ext" SHA256. I noticed that AWS S3 stores SHA-256 checksums in base64 encoding. Should I convert my checksum to base64 before passing it, or is the hexadecimal format acceptable?

@jarmod if i use headers in presignedUploadURL I'm getting
<HeadersNotSigned>x-amz-checksum-sha256, x-amz-checksum-algorithm</HeadersNotSigned>

If you add the checksum headers when creating the pre-signed URL, then the client that later invokes the pre-signed URL must also send the same headers in its HTTP request.

@jarmod Yes, I am adding ChecksumAlgorithm and ChecksumSHA256 in the signed URL headers while uploading the file, but I'm receiving the error <HeadersNotSigned>x-amz-checksum-sha256, x-amz-checksum-algorithm</HeadersNotSigned>. Additionally, the generated Presigned URL parameters include x-amz-checksum-sha256: 55mctU7OjqTlJwxJoDoAyE9kkf28%2FD3jAkCNiRgZM48%3D.
